# Removing element from te array function

Tags: c++, algorithm, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

Is there any already implemented function that has initialArray, sizeOfInitialArray, outArray, and sizeOfOutArray parameters, takes one array and removes specific element, after it creates new array of the exact-element size, something like this below:

```
void removeElement(int *initialArray, int sizeOfInitialArray, int *& outArray, int & sizeOfOutArray)
 {
       // some code here
 }
```

I know I remember there was some function exactly processing the code as I want, buy I forgot the name of that function.

Thanks in advance for your efforts.

Comment: The signature does not supply the element to be removed.

Comment: I don't know of any standard function that would meet this (rather specific) requirement.  But if you just use `std::vector<int>` it is trivial to do this yourself.

Comment: nah using remove and realloc would be more appropriate to my case, but thanks anyway Charles! :)

Comment: You may be thinking of the [`std::remove_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove_copy) algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see [remove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove/) from stl..it will process inplace then you may create a new array and return back..

NotTested! complete code will be

```
#include <algorithm>
void removeElement(int *initialArray, int sizeOfInitialArray, int ValueToBeRemoved, int      *& outArray, int & sizeOfOutArray)
{
 int* endOfArray = initialArray+sizeOfInitialArray;
 endOfArray = remove(initialArray,endOfArray,ValueToBeRemoved);
 sizeOfOutArray = (endOfArray - initialArray);
 outArray = new int[sizeOfOutArray];
 memcpy(outArray,initialArray,(endOfArray - initialArray)*sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: Nice, just made me thinking in completely different way! Thanks, Semih.

Answer (score 0):

you can use erase-remove idiom

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

bool f (int value) { return value % 2; }

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 10, 11, 2, 3, -1 };
    v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), f), v.end());
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " ")); 
}
```

If I understand you right